# How to customize a permalink (URL) structure?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, functions, customization

i am using $post->guid to get the URL of an attached file to my post. the output is something like this: http://example.com/foo/ [where foo is the file name].
now i want to make a URL like http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/foo/
how can i code that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUID field is *not* a URL and should never be used for that purpose. It's a unique identifier that happens to look like a URL, but it should never be trusted as such.

WordPress has a number of functions for retreiving attachment URLs and files:

[`get_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)

[`get_attached_media`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media)

[`the_attachment_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_attachment_link)

[`get_attachment_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link)

[`wp_get_attachment_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link)

[`wp_get_attachment_image`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

[`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

[`wp_get_attachment_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

[`wp_get_attachment_thumb_file`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_thumb_file)

[`wp_get_attachment_thumb_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_thumb_url)

[`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

The function `wp_get_attachment_image` is probably what you're looking for in this case.

Comment: tnx. i used wp_get_attachment_url ()